# Moving android keyboard

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard

I'm developing an app using xamarin android. And I was wondering if there is a way to move the SoftInput keyboard? e.g. using padding from or margin from the bottom?
Thanks

Comment: since the keyboard is a standalone application, you can't change it's views' margin\padding\etc. If you want a keyboard not in the bottom, you will have to implement your own as a part of your app.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko you mean like a custom keyboard? I have to create one if I want it at the top?

Comment: you may create a complete keyboard, or just a view in your app, pressing on buttons of which will add characters to your app's edittexts

Comment: ok Thanks for your help